# How Do I add prettyprint to a drupal page? In particular where do I add body onload="prettyPrint()"

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal

I have never used druapal before.  So I need specific information on how to do this.  For a normal page this is how pretty print works:  http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Now I need to know how to do this for a specific page in Drupal. AND in particular onLoad method for the body. Where do specify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't add an `onload` handler to the body, you can always add a `<script>prettyPrint()</script>` element at the end of the page instead.